# Will "go generate" change to the directory to run script?

Tags: go

I'm trying to generate some code by several tools. So, I've write a file data.go as

```
package main           

//go:generate awk -v OFILE=names.go -f gen_table.awk $HOME/prj/header.h     
//go:generate gofmt -w names.go             
//go:generate ./gen_index_html.sh
```

The generated names.go won't formatted automatically, so, I added the second line to force the correct format. And I assume it runs subsequently.
Will Go generate jump into this directory before run these command? Because the script gen_index_html.sh just accept work in current directory.

Comment: Which directory is *this directory* in the above question? How is it related to current directory, i.e. the directory in which you run `go generate`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/#hdr-Generate_Go_files_by_processing_source):

> The generator is run in the package's source directory.

So, whatever command is run with generate will be run in the same directory as the file containing the generate directive.

Multiple generate directives in one file are executed one at a time in source code order.